# EBCDIC to ASCII not working Properly

Tags: c, ascii, mainframe, ebcdic

I have to process a file which comes from mainframes. There are some Non-Latin text in the file. I have to process this Non-Latin characters for some invalid characters. As the mainframe encodes the data in `EBCDIC` format, I have to convert it to `ASCII` to do the validation.

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7734331/3747770) code to convert from `EBCDIC` to `ASCII`. But when I execute the program for the sample input, I am getting `Hello there]` instead of `Hello there!`. 
I also checked sample input against the `EBCDIC` [table](http://www.astrodigital.org/digital/ebcdic.html).

I also generated the lookup table using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7734349/3747770). But the same result.

- Am I doing anything wrong? Or is the lookup table wrong?
- Is there anyother way to validate for invalid chars without converting to `ASCII`?

Sample code is below...

```
#include <stdio.h>

static const unsigned char e2a[256] = {
          0,  1,  2,  3,156,  9,134,127,151,141,142, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
         16, 17, 18, 19,157,133,  8,135, 24, 25,146,143, 28, 29, 30, 31,
        128,129,130,131,132, 10, 23, 27,136,137,138,139,140,  5,  6,  7,
        144,145, 22,147,148,149,150,  4,152,153,154,155, 20, 21,158, 26,
         32,160,161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168, 91, 46, 60, 40, 43, 33,
         38,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,176,177, 93, 36, 42, 41, 59, 94,
         45, 47,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,124, 44, 37, 95, 62, 63,
        186,187,188,189,190,191,192,193,194, 96, 58, 35, 64, 39, 61, 34,
        195, 97, 98, 99,100,101,102,103,104,105,196,197,198,199,200,201,
        202,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,203,204,205,206,207,208,
        209,126,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,210,211,212,213,214,215,
        216,217,218,219,220,221,222,223,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,
        123, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73,232,233,234,235,236,237,
        125, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82,238,239,240,241,242,243,
         92,159, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90,244,245,246,247,248,249,
         48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57,250,251,252,253,254,255
};

void ebcdicToAscii (unsigned char *s)
{
    while (*s)
    {
        *s = e2a[(int) (*s)];
        s++;
    }
}

int main (void) {
    unsigned char str[] = "\xc8\x85\x93\x93\x96\x40\xa3\x88\x85\x99\x85\x5a";
    ebcdicToAscii (str);
    printf ("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your table is wrong. `0x5a` as ebcdic is indeed `!`, but your translation table decodes it to `93` (`0x5d`), which in ascii is `]`, not `!`.

Comment: Note, no need for the cast `(int)` in `e2a[(int) (*s)]`.  `e2a[*s]` is sufficient.

Comment: This table also is attempting more than "EBCDIC to ASCII" as [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) only defined codes 0 to 127 and this table emits values greater  than 127 and does not contain "non-Latin characters".  Certainly OP is using some flavor of _extended_ ASCII.

Comment: How are you getting the data from the Mainframe? And why can't you use it's built-in capabilities, and ask the technical support stuff to show you one that is working so you need to do.... nothing? Rolling-your-own character-set conversion is... unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Your lookup table is wrong. It converts EBCDIC value 0x5A ('!') to (decimal) 93. ASCII decimal 93 is an ']'. So, your application works fine, it outputs the ']' character. You indicate that you generated the lookup table from a python sample that uses [cp500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC_500) which is IBM code page 500. This code page indeed maps EBCDIC value 0x5A to the ']' character. If you would use the character set listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) for your lookup table, things would be ok.

Answer (score 2):

There is a utility called `īconv` in USS on z/OS that will do the conversion for you.  A full reference can be found [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.cbcux01/iconvushell.htm) of the code pages it supports.

That said, should you choose to roll your own here are a few suggestions.  First, EBCDIC to ASCII has a few subtle things to consider.  For EBCDIC there are a variety of code pages that are in use for z/OS systems.  Here is a [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC_code_pages) that provide more detail.  In general EBCDIC is Code Page 1047 which works for most North America users.  However, there are other code pages which would impact what you are doing.  For instance, in the UK they would commonly use Code Page 37.  This means there are subtle differences in character translation.

So, you would need one translation table for each code page your translating from to properly convert special characters that are unique to the code pages.

Also, this is pure preference but I prefer seeing the code in hex rather than decimal for this kind of data (translation).  Its often how people will refer to characters on Z

```
static const unsigned char e2a[256] = {
      0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x9c, 0x09, 0x86, 0x7f, 0x97, 0x8d, 0x8e, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f,
      0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x9d, 0x85, 0x08, 0x87, 0x18, 0x19, 0x92, 0x8f, 0x1c, 0x1d, 0x1e, 0x1f,
      0x80, 0x81, 0x82, 0x83, 0x84, 0x0a, 0x17, 0x1b, 0x88, 0x89, 0x8a, 0x8b, 0x8c, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07,
      0x90, 0x91, 0x16, 0x93, 0x94, 0x95, 0x96, 0x04, 0x98, 0x99, 0x9a, 0x9b, 0x14, 0x15, 0x9e, 0x1a,
      0x20, 0xa0, 0xa1, 0xa2, 0xa3, 0xa4, 0xa5, 0xa6, 0xa7, 0xa8, 0x5b, 0x2e, 0x3c, 0x28, 0x2b, 0x21,
      0x26, 0xa9, 0xaa, 0xab, 0xac, 0xad, 0xae, 0xaf, 0xb0, 0xb1, 0x5d, 0x24, 0x2a, 0x29, 0x3b, 0x5e,
      0x2d, 0x2f, 0xb2, 0xb3, 0xb4, 0xb5, 0xb6, 0xb7, 0xb8, 0xb9, 0x7c, 0x2c, 0x25, 0x5f, 0x3e, 0x3f,
      0xba, 0xbb, 0xbc, 0xbd, 0xbe, 0xbf, 0xc0, 0xc1, 0xc2, 0x60, 0x3a, 0x23, 0x40, 0x27, 0x3d, 0x22,
      0xc3, 0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66, 0x67, 0x68, 0x69, 0xc4, 0xc5, 0xc6, 0xc7, 0xc8, 0xc9,
      0xca, 0x6a, 0x6b, 0x6c, 0x6d, 0x6e, 0x6f, 0x70, 0x71, 0x72, 0xcb, 0xcc, 0xcd, 0xce, 0xcf, 0xd0,
      0xd1, 0x7e, 0x73, 0x74, 0x75, 0x76, 0x77, 0x78, 0x79, 0x7a, 0xd2, 0xd3, 0xd4, 0xd5, 0xd6, 0xd7,
      0xd8, 0xd9, 0xda, 0xdb, 0xdc, 0xdd, 0xde, 0xdf, 0xe0, 0xe1, 0xe2, 0xe3, 0xe4, 0xe5, 0xe6, 0xe7,
      0x7b, 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x45, 0x46, 0x47, 0x48, 0x49, 0xe8, 0xe9, 0xea, 0xeb, 0xec, 0xed,
      0x7d, 0x4a, 0x4b, 0x4c, 0x4d, 0x4e, 0x4f, 0x50, 0x51, 0x52, 0xee, 0xef, 0xf0, 0xf1, 0xf2, 0xf3,
      0x5c, 0x9f, 0x53, 0x54, 0x55, 0x56, 0x57, 0x58, 0x59, 0x5a, 0xf4, 0xf5, 0xf6, 0xf7, 0xf8, 0xf9,
      0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x39, 0xfa, 0xfb, 0xfc, 0xfd, 0xfe, 0xff
 };
```